# error while loading shared libraries: libR.so

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I installed R on redhat using the following commands:

- ./configure  --enable-R-shlib –with-readline=no –with-
- make clean
- make
- make install

I have the R_HOME installed in /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3.
First I had the issue of starting Rtudio Server browser Interface. So I linked:

- ln -s /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/bin /usr/local/bin
- ln -s /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/bin /usr/bin
- ln -s /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/lib /us/local/lib

Now I can open RStudio Server web interface, but I can't login. And when I try the following command I got:

- sudo rstudio-server verify-installation

I got : **/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession: error while loading shared libraries: libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
rstudio-server start/running, process 14677**

Any ideas about how solving this problem ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you mean by

> So I linked:
>   /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/bin to /usr/local/bin
>   /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/bin /usr/bin
>   /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/lib /us/local/lib

On a normal system, R is installed properly following `configure ...; make; make install` and found via the `$PATH`.  There is nothing else you need to do.  Besides installing RStudio from `rpm` or `deb`.  You *could* also install R that route, and that may indeed be advisable ...

Comment: I added the used command to do it above. Can you show me how to install R-3.2.3 using rpm ? Many thanks

Comment: The commands above have the potential to complete hose your system. Please try to get help from a more experienced local Unix user, or follow the existing documentation more closely.  *Nobody* ever suggested the commands above.

Comment: The following site suggested the same commands for the same error but for a package. http://rpy.sourceforge.net/legacy/rpy_faq.html . Do you have a document that explains the installation of R on Redhat ?

Comment: You are confusing documentation for the (old, deprecated) R to Python bridge with what you think you should for R itself and RStudio.  That is not advisable.  From what I recall there is a dedicated mailing list for R on RedHat-based systems:  [r-sig-fedora](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-fedora). You could try that.

Comment: I have unlinked the previous folders. So now I have the first error when executing" sudo rstudio-server verify-installation" which is Unable to find an installation of R on the system (which R didn't return valid output); Unable to locate R binary by scanning standard locations. Any ideas ?